# Can the axiom of choice be proved with ZF+Tarski axiom?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

Can choice be proved with ZF+[Tarski axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following the link found in the Wikipedia article about the [Tarski–Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory), the required proof (by Tarski himself!) can be found beginning on p.181 of his article ["On the well-ordered subsets of any set"](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm32/fm32115.pdf) published in 1939 in "Fundamenta Mathematicae" (in fact, Tarski shows that his axiom implies the well-ordering theorem/axiom, which is known to be equivalent to the axiom of choice).

Comment: Interesting, it is very powerful:
"It is Tarski's axiom that distinguishes TG from other axiomatic set theories. Tarski's axiom also implies the axioms of infinity, choice,[1][2] and power set.[3][4] It also implies the existence of inaccessible cardinals, thanks to which the ontology of TG is much richer than that of conventional set theories such as ZFC. "

Then the other natural question would be why ZFC is much more popular than the Tarski-Grothendieck.  I conjecture GT must have more contra intuitive results than for example the ZFC Banach Tarski paradox.